# getLine() does't seem to work after first input - C++

Tags: c++, string, user-input, cin, cout

I'm currently new to C++ and learning the basic syntax.

I'm exploring how getLine() works and I'm trying to compare the standard input and a getline().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string name1;
string name2;

cout << "Type your name please: ";
cin >> name1;
cout << "Your name is: " << name1 << endl;

cout << endl;

cout << "Type your name again please: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, name2);
cout << "Your name is: " << name2 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Type your name please: John Doe
Your name is: John

Type your name again please: John Doe
Your name is: John Doe
```

Current Output:

```
Type your name please: John Doe
Your name is: John

Type your name again please: Your name is: Doe
```

What may be the issue causing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`cin.ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is documented here. How many characters are you skipping from the first input? How many should you be skipping? Hint: there's an example on that page of how to do exactly this correctly.

Comment: The code shown assumes your platform console input line termination when you thwap the enter/return key is a single char. That isn't always the case.

Comment: So many examples on the internet of people using `ignore` incorrectly. Why? Because they copied it from someone else using it incorrectly. There's no substitute for understanding what you are doing. Find a good reference, at read up on how these functions actually work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see `cin >> name1;` reads only up to the first whitespace. What remains in the input buffer is  `Doe\n`. (Notice the first character is a space).

Now `cin.ignore();` will ignore 1 character (the white space in this case). The input buffer now contains `Doe\n`. See here for more details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Next `getline(cin, name2);` will read all the data up to the next new line. That is `Doe`, which you get as second output.

---

I think you wanted to discard the complete input, instead of just one character. This should do it:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should clear the input stream and ignore not only one character but all in the stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string name1;
    std::string name2;

    std::cout << "Type your name please: ";
    std::cin >> name1;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Your name is: " << name1 << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Type your name again please: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name2);
    std::cout << "Your name is: " << name2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```